# Traffic Light Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, graph-traversal

Say you have a standard graph with values attached to each node and each edge.
You want to go from one node on the graph to another in the shortest amount of time.
The amount of time you have taken so far to traverse this graph will be known as T.
If an edge has value V, traversing that edge will add V to your time spent (T += V).
If a node has a value N, traversing that node will force you to wait until your time spent is divisible by N (T += (N - T % N) % N).

You can think of this like streets and traffic lights.
Driving on a street takes a constant amount of time to reach the other end.
Driving through a traffic light takes the amount of time you have to wait for it to turn green.

For example, lets say you have this graph:

```
S--6--[1]--2--[7]
       |       |
       3       2
       |       |
      [9]--3--[6]--1--E
```

Just at a glance, the top path looks faster because it has shorter edges and a shorter delay.
However, the bottom route turns out to be faster.  Let's compute the bottom first:

```
Start: 0 + 6 -> 6
       6 % 1 == 0 # We can pass
       6 + 3 -> 9
       9 % 9 == 0 # We can pass
       9 + 3 -> 12
       12 % 6 == 0 # We can pass
       12 + 1 -> 13
End:   13
```

And then the top:

```
Start: 0 + 6 -> 6
       6 % 1 == 0 # We can pass
       6 + 2 -> 8
       8 % 7 != 0 # Have to wait
       8 + 6 -> 14
       14 % 7 == 0 # We can pass
       14 + 2 -> 16
       16 % 6 != 0 # Have to wait
       16 + 2 -> 18
       18 % 6 == 0 # We can pass
       18 + 1 -> 19
End:   19
```

As you can see, the bottom is much shorter.
At small sizes like this it's easier to calculate but at city sizes, you'd need to use some sort of traversal algorithm.
Does anyone know if there's any sort of solution besides brute force?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is known as shortest path search problem and can be solved by Dijkstra's algorithm in polynomial time. When the lenght of the path is computed, the amount of time spent waiting in the destination vertex should also be added(except for the destination vertex). So it is still the shortest path search problem, but the weight function is slightly different from simple edges' weights sum.

Comment: Look at the example I gave.  The shortest path isn't the correct solution.

Comment: @nullreff It is correct. The definition of path lenght here is not just a  sum of all edges' weights.